# How to recover an html file overwritten by TextEdit (Mac)

Tags: macos, textedit

For some reasons, I decided to open a Javascript file in .html format using Mac's TextEdit.

Instead of loading the .html in text format, as the name TextEdit implied, it rendered the .html file.

Then I did something incredibly stupid. I went to "Format" and "Make Plain Text" and "OK" to "Convert this document to plain text". After that, it ask me:

"Are you sure you want to modify the document in place?" With 3 options

Overwrite, Cancel, Duplicate.

I choose "Cancel".

Here is the kicker. It changed my .html file into .rtf. (I think it should have been named .wtf). It didn't even ask me to save. Is there any chance that I can recover my original .html file?

Comment: I assume you're not using TimeMachine to create backups?

Comment: You assumed correctly. :(

Comment: there's no such thing as "html format".  html is plaintext code.  Just reopen the file and manually save it with an html filetype